# ドロップダウンリストに連動してURLを生成したい

Tags: asp.net, razor

ASP.NET MVC の質問です。
ページ上にドロップダウンリストがあって、ユーザーの選択に応じて

```
 /ドロップダウンで選択した値/{controller}/{action}
```

のURLにリダイレクトするにはどのように実装すればよいでしょうか？

たとえば、ロケールと言語がそれぞれドロップダウンで選択できるページがあり、初期状態では「現在のロケールと言語」が選択された状態になっています。

ユーザーがロケールに「jp」、言語に「ja」を選択したら

```
/jp/ja/{controller}/{action}
```

のページに遷移するイメージです。
（この場合、ロケール選択時と言語選択時で２回遷移が発生することになりますが、それで構いません）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず`Application_Start`(`RouteConfig`)でロケールを含むルートを登録します。

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LocaleAndLanguage",
    url: "{locale}/{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

次にパターンのパラメーターをアクションメソッドに追加します。
上の例では`locale`と`language`という名前ですので、

```
string locale,
string language,
```

となります。

このように設定したうえでビューのルートパラメーターを指定する箇所(`Url.Action`など)で`locale`と`language`を指定すれば、仕様に合うURLが生成されると思います。

```
@Url.Action("Hoge", new
{
    locale = "jp",
    language = "ja",
})
```

また「リダイレクト」ですが、実際にはJavaScriptのイベントを処理することになると思います。
設計次第ですが、単純に`form`を送信するような実装にもできます。

```
<script>

$('#@Html.IdFor(_ => _.Language)').change(function(){ $('form').submit(); });

</script>
```

サーバ側では`Controller.Session`プロパティ等に値を保存しておけばよいでしょう。